# How to get only particular key value pair from json data and store in variable in node js

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I have a sample json data,which I need to add in to different collections in mongodb.But I dont want whole json data.For example,

```
jsondata=
  {"widget": {
"debug": "on",
"window": {
    "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
    "name": "main_window",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 500
},
"image": { 
    "src": "Images/Sun.png",
    "name": "sun1",
    "hOffset": 250,

},
"text": {
    "data": "Click Here",
    "size": 36,
    "style": "bold",

}}
```

In this json I want window key in one collection,simillarly image key in another mongo collection.
So I was thinking if I can save that key value pair in one variable,then I can add that variable in to collection.For this I was trying for each

```
var jsondat=JSON.parse(jsondata);
for(var exKey in jsondat) {
 console.log("entering");
 var b=stringdata[exKey].image;

 console.log(b);
}
```

But I was unable to get that image key data.Is this the right approach for this?can someone help me out in this.
 My expected result would be:
In one variable,The value of window key should be saved in json format.
Simillarly image and text keyvalues in another variables.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you post your expected result?

Comment: yes for window key we are having value as {
    "title": "Sample Konfabulator Widget",
    "name": "main_window",
    "width": 500,
    "height": 500
}..I want this to be saved in a variable as json

Answer (score 0):

Why aren't you fetching window and image simply from the object as key like:

```
var window= jsondata.widget.window;
var image = jsondata.widget.image;
```

and save them in mongo db

```
db.window.insert(window)
db.image.insert(image)
```

Tell me If I understand it right.

Comment: Will window get the key value in it?

Comment: Not working.Unable to parse Message Hub data [TypeError: Cannot read property 'window' of undefined]

Comment: .widget Not working.Cannot read property 'window' of undefined

Comment: that means your json is not valid.. first parse the json and follow above approach.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see much problem.

```
var jsondat=JSON.parse(jsondata);
for(var exKey in jsondat.widget) {
 console.log("entering");
 console.log(exKey);
 if(exKey === 'image'){
  db.image.insert(jsondat.widget[exKey]);
 }else if(exKey === 'window'){
  db.window.insert(jsondat.widget[exKey]);
 }
 // or db.getCollection(exKey).insert(jsondat.widget[exKey]);
}
```

But I would also add that normalization is not desirable in MongoDB, you should use embedding more because you won't be able to join collections later on if you want to collate data. But that's a general idea, maybe in your requirement you want different collection.

Comment: Not working.Unable to parse Message Hub data [TypeError: Cannot read property 'window' of undefined] –

Comment: .widget Not working.Cannot read property 'window' of undefined

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in several ways.

### Method#1

```
var arr = [];
for(var i in jsondata.widget){
  if(typeof(jsondata.widget[i])==='object'){
   arr.push(jsondata.widget[i]);
  }
};
console.log(arr);
```

### Method#2

You can use `unserscore` utility library to get in easy

```
var _=require('underscore');
var arr = [];
_.each(jsondata.widget,function(o){
  if(typeof(o)==='object'){
   arr.push(o);
  }
});

console.log(arr);
```

Now you can access all the object by index

**Output**

```
[ { title: 'Sample Konfabulator Widget',
    name: 'main_window',
    width: 500,
    height: 500 },
  { src: 'Images/Sun.png', name: 'sun1', hOffset: 250 },
  { data: 'Click Here', size: 36, style: 'bold' } ]
```

### Method#3

Try to get separate value of each inner keys

```
var window= jsondata.widget.window;
var image= jsondata.widget.image;
var text= jsondata.widget.text;
```

**Edit**

```
var obj={
  "json": {
    "window": {
      "title": "sample",
      "name": "sam"
    },
    "image": {
      "src": "Images/Sun.png",
      "name": "sun1",
      "hOffset": 250
    }
  }
}

console.log(obj.json.window)

result-> {title: "sample", name: "sam"}
```

Comment: Not working.Unable to parse Message Hub data [TypeError: Cannot read property 'window' of undefined] –

Comment: .widget Not working..Cannot read property 'window' of undefined

Comment: Can't believe, it should work, it's common code I just test it and working fine all methods.

Comment: Hi ..It is not working ,if I have complex json something like,jsondata={
 "json": {
  "window": {
   "title": "sample",
   "name": "sam"
  }
 }
}

Comment: It's not a valid json

Comment: Can you post your JSON in your question

Comment: {
 "json": {
  "window": {
   "title": "sample",
   "name": "sam"
  },
  "image": {
   "src": "Images/Sun.png",
   "name": "sun1",
   "hOffset": 250

  }
 }
}

Comment: Your `json` key is always fix? mean every time you'll get in this format?

Comment: Yes the json is fixed

Comment: If it's fixed then why not you can use console.log(obj.json.window)?